# "Supposing Jane ______ with us, what would you do?"

Tags: tenses, conditionals, progressive-aspect, protasis

In this sentence:

> Supposing Jane ______ with us, what would you do?

The available options for filling in that blank were:

1. would come
2. came
3. will come
4. has come
5. is coming

Could I know which is correct?

Comment: Your list is incomplete.  **¨comes¨** and **¨were to come¨** should be considered.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** Your test-giver **probably** wants you to select choice #2 *“came”*, but this is an extremely poorly designed test not only because one could reasonably argue that either of choices #4 and #5 might also work for some speakers and situations, but also because many other completely valid and perfectly common possibilities are unconscionably omitted from your severely limited — and limiting — available choices.

---

### Stealth Conditionals: *Twenty-five possible solutions*

This test is apparently trying to get you to demonstrate your understanding of what sorts of verb tenses, moods, and aspects are allowable in English conditionals.

If I’m right about its purpose, then it is not, in my considered opinion, a very good test of that. Although there are a few obviously wrong answers, more than one possible “right enough” answer may be possible, of which most were ***alas!*** not even given you as potential choices.  It’s really not a good test at all.

The only general rule for you to keep in mind is that conditionals always have either a present-tense form or else past-tense form in their protasis, meaning their “if” part.  This constrains what can come in the apodosis, the “then” part.

You are being force to choose a protasis, and have been given no freedom in the apodosis, which always uses the conditional form *would do* in your test question.  Since the apodosis form is known, only so many possible protasis forms are allowable, most of which were not even provided to you as valid answers.

You haven’t said whether whoever gave the test allows for more than one possible answer, or for no possible answers.  One thing that’s certain is that you weren’t given enough different possible answers to choose from if the goal is to test you on how to put the verbs in the two halves together using different tenses, aspects, and moods.

Therefore, although it is by no means the only answer possible, of the limited answers you were rather unfortunately forced to choose from, the best answer is arguably your second choice, *came*:

1. Supposing Jane **came** with us, what would you do? (*choice #2*)

That’s because it’s really the same sentence as:

2. If Jane **came** with us, what **would** you do? (*not, alas, a provided choice*)

If I wanted to emphasize the hypothetical, I would have chosen a hypothetical-*were* construct:

3. If Jane **were coming** with us, what **would** you do? (*not, alas, a provided choice*)
4. Supposing Jane **were coming** with us, what **would** you do? (*not, alas, a provided choice*)

This is essentially the same as the *came* case in the simple past, in that the protasis (the “if” part) of the implied conditional is in the past and the apodosis (the “then” part) is in the conditional.

However, one slight difference is how with *were coming*, that version is also emphasizing the progressive aspect by using an inflection of *be* with an *-ing* verb following it, normally analysed as a present participle.

Although I am not one of them, for some people that hypothetical *were* is more formal or literary than conversational, or is too unreal, so they would just use the simple past in the protasis.  They might choose a simple present for the assumptive part:

5. Supposing Jane **comes** with us, what **would** you do? (*not, alas, a provided choice*)

But that was not among your possible choices, forcing you to use this instead:

6. Supposing Jane **is coming** with us, what **would** you do? (*choice #5, but not, I feel, a very good one*)

That last one (#6) feels wrong(-ish) to me personally, and I wouldn’t likely generate that sentence, but but some people might say it.

It might also be possible to use choice #4, however, which means another possible answer of your allowable choices is this one:

7. Supposing Jane **has come** with us, what **would** you do? (*choice #4, but not my favorite*)

Sentence #6 above with *supposing* and *is coming* both together feels a bit funny to me. It seems to have too much *“-ing”* in it; I also feel that for me at least, there is a mismatch between *is coming* in the present and *would do* in the conditional. That’s why I prefer the ***“if past, then conditional”*** formulation, no matter whether you use the hypothetical *were* or the simple past.

Versions of the sentence where the apodosis (again, the “then” part) is no longer in the conditional can also make fine sense, and are less pie-in-the-sky hypotheticals that way.  These take a present-tense verb form in the protasis (again, the “if” part).  For example:

8. If Jane **comes** with us, what **will** you do? (*not, alas, a provided choice*)
9. Supposing Jane **comes** with us, what **will** you do? (*not, alas, a provided choice*)

Notice that in 8 and 9, since the protasis is now in the present, the apodosis most naturally falls into the conditional.

It might also be possible to use your provided choice #4, however, which means another possible answer of your allowable choices could be this one:

10. Supposing Jane **has come** with us, what **would** you do? (*choice #4, but not my favorite*)

That isn’t too terribly bad.  Yes, it’s a present *has* paired with a conditional *would*, but people do sometimes say things like that.

For some reason I can’t pin down, I don’t much like the *supposing – is coming* combination.  Too much *-ing* or something If you really want *is coming* in the apodosis, then there are also possibile ways of using *suppose* in place of *supposing* there.

I still think that a present tense (which is what *has* actually is, even if it is using a past participle with it; that makes it a “present perfect” construction) in the protasis calls for something else in the apodosis:

11. **Suppose** Jane **has come** with us; what **will** you do? (*not, alas, a provided choice*)
12. **Suppose** Jane **comes** with us; what **will** you do? (*not, alas, a provided choice*)
13. **Suppose** Jane **were to come** with us; what **would** you do? (*not, alas, a provided choice*)
14. **Suppose** Jane **were coming** with us; what **would** you do? (*not, alas, a provided choice*)

Of those four, the one with *comes* in the simple present and the one with *has come* in the present perfect are the least hypothetical, since it’s no longer an *“if X **were**, then Y **would**”* type of conditional. That shift in nuance into the normal present tense might mean the speaker thinks it more likely that Jane will be with us than in the two *were* cases.

Those four examples given in 11–14 are respectively equivalent to these *if–then* conditionals:

15. If Jane **has come** with us, what **will** you do?  (*not, alas, a provided choice*)
16. If Jane **comes** with us, what **will** you do? (*not, alas, a provided choice*)
17. If Jane **were to come** with us, what **would** you do? (*not, alas, a provided choice*)
18. If Jane **were coming** with us; what **would** you do? (*not, alas, a provided choice*)

By switching *supposing* to *suppose*, you swap one non-tense form (present participle) to another (infinitive).  Whether you choose to analyse that infinitive form *suppose* as an imperative use or a concessive subjunctive one, it is still an untensed verb that shows no time aspect.

### Summary

I don’t think much of the test you were given.  It’s far too limiting.  Here again were your choices:

1. ***would come***: This is wrong; never use [***epistemic***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality) *would* in a conditional’s protasis.  ***Deontic*** *would* is sometimes possible in that position, but rather rarer; see below.
2. ***came***: This one is the best fit for the protasis given the limited apodosis you were given.
3. ***will come***: Always wrong: never use epistemic *will* (a marker of the future) in an English protasis.
4. ***has come***: Possible perhaps, but hardly optimal.
5. ***is coming***: Potentially possible in some speakers, but I really don’t care for this one myself.

---

#### PS: Deontic Protases

For an example of using ***deontic*** *would* in the protasis, consider this stealth polite request asking Jane to sit down so we can get started:

19. If Jane **would** please take her seat, we **could** get going.
20. If Jane **would** please take her seat, we **can** get going.
21. If Jane **would** please take her seat, we **will** get going.
22. If Jane **would** please take her seat, **we’ll** get going.

Recasting those using *suppose* in the protasis instead of *if* is possible, which is more in the style of your own original:

23. Suppose Jane **would** kindly take her seat; **could** we then get going?

It is critically important that you understand this is a completely different use of *would*, and therefore different rules. In all five of sentences 19–23, that’s a **deontic** *would*, not an epistemic one, so the normal rule forbidding *would* from appearing in the conditional’s protasis does not apply here.

There are other valid modal possibilities and combinations for that sort of request.  For example:

24. If Jane **might** please take her seat, we **could** get going.
    (*this one is a bit standoffish yet more demanding at the same time*)
25. If Jane **should** please take her seat, we **could** get going.
    (*a very rare possibility at most, and only then in highly formal or literary registers now tantamount to archaic in regular conversational registers*)

Although I have given 25 possible answers, please do not assume that this posting has exhausted all possible approaches to English conditionals.  It most definitely has not, for with English just as in another famous language derived from it, [***“There’s more than one way to do it!”***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)

Comment: +1 for the effort. And, of course, I'll note that just a simple "were" would suffice as well.

Comment: Supposing tchrist wrote the test, who would replant the forests cut down to provide the paper?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It was indeed a very limited kind of test, and I selected "came" impulsively because it seemed to roll down the tongue this way.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Who says tchrist uses paper? You can't run Perl scripts on paper.